# Saving a custom customer attribute in observer

Tags: magento, magento-1.9, observers

I have created an observer for customer registration.

Inside it i have the following code segment.

```
public function customerRegistrationSuccess($observer)
{
        $customer = $observer->getEvent()->getCustomer();
        $deviceName="web";
     //log written
        $customer->setDevice_used($deviceName);
        $customer->save();
       //log written again
}
```

and i have an install file with code:

```
<?php $installer = $this;
      $installer->startSetup();
      $this->addAttribute('customer', 'device_used', array(
'label'     => 'Device Used',
'visible'   => 1,
'input'     => 'text',
'type'      => 'varchar',
'required'  => 0,
"unique"    => 0,
'position'  => 120,
'sort_order'=> 80,

));
$attribute = Mage::getSingleton('eav/config')->getAttribute('customer', 'device_used');
  $attribute->setData('used_in_forms', array(
'adminhtml_customer',
'checkout_register',
'customer_account_create',
'customer_account_edit',
'adminhtml_checkout'
 ));    
            $attribute->setData('is_user_defined', 0);
 $attribute->save();

 $installer->endSetup();
 ?>
```

but no such attribute is being created. What could possibly be wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I think your set call in customerRegistrationSuccess is incorrect. It should be

```
$customer->setDeviceUsed($deviceName);
```

Alternatively you could use

```
$customer->setData('device_used',$deviceName);
```

Both achieve the same thing.

If that doesn't work you will need to check that the install script ran correctly. Check the core_resource DB table to see if there's an  entry for your module and go from there.